# Escaping backslash in Ansible playbook

Tags: yaml, ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook that calls `get_url` to download a file BUT the URL contains a backslash

```
http://cijboss:8080/jenkins/job/prod/186/org.myorg\$ear/artifact/org.org/ear/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ear-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

I have tried double quotes, single quotes, \ escape sequences, etc. Have tried the many things found in Jinja2 and YAML escaping documents and nothing works. When I feed the URL through an ad hoc command, it downloads the file just fine.

```
ansible <server> -m get_url -u user -a "http://cijboss:8080/jenkins/job/prod/186/org.myorg\$ear/artifact/org.org/ear/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ear-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" dest=/home/user"
```

Each time the playbook runs, the url contains a double backslash. How does one properly escape this?

Update: Below is the yml playbook file.

```
    ---
    - hosts: jboss
      remote_user: jboss
    tasks:
      - name: Get Ear file
        get_url: url="http://cijboss:8080/jenkins/job/prod/186/org.myorg\$ear/artifact/org.org/ear/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ear-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"  dest=/home/jboss mode=0755
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it? -> `%5C`

```
http://example.com/jenkins/../../domain%5C$project/../app.ear
```

Comment: I did. Output ends up being: ..domain%5c$project/..  and results in a 404

Comment: `$` is a special character in URLs. Escape it, too. Code: `%24`